# Should I create a docker container or docker start a stopped container?

Tags: docker

From the docker philosophy's point of view it is more advisable:

1. create a container every time we need to use a certain environment and then remove it after use (`docker run <image>` all the time); or
2. create a container for a specific environment (`docker run <image>`), stop it when it is not necessary and whenever it is initialized again (`docker start <container>`);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `docker rm` the old container and `docker run` a new one, you will always get a clean filesystem that starts from exactly what's in the original image (plus any volume mounts).  You will also fairly routinely need to delete and recreate a container to change basic options: if you need to change a port mapping or an environment variable, or if you need to update the image to have a newer version of the software, you'll be forced to delete the container.

This is enough reason for me to make my standard process be to *always* delete and recreate the container.

```sh
# docker build -t the-image .  # can be done first if needed
docker stop the-container      # so it can cleanly shut down and be removed
docker rm the-container
docker run --name the-container ... the-image
```

Other orchestrators like Docker Compose and Kubernetes are also set up to automatically delete and recreate the container (or Kubernetes pod) if there's a change; their standard workflows do not generally involve restarting containers in-place.

I almost never use `docker start`.  In a Compose-based workflow I generally use only `docker-compose up -d`, letting it restart things if needed; `docker-compose down` if I need the CPU/memory resources the container stack was using but not in routine work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm talking with regards to my experience in the industry so take my answer with a grain of salt, because there might be no hard evidence or reference to the theory.

Here's the answer:

**TL;DR:**
In short, you never need the `docker stop` and `docker start` because taking this approach is unreliable and you might lose the container and all the data inside if no proper action is applied beforehand.

**Long answer:**
You should only work with images and not the containers. Whenever you need some specific data or you need the image to have some customization, you better use `docker save` to have the image for future use.

If you're just testing out on your local machine, or in your dev virtual machine on a remote host, you're free to use either one you like. I personally take each of the approaches on different scenarios.

But if you're talking about a production environment, you'd better use some orchestration tool; it could be as simple and easy to work with as `docker-compose` or `docker swarm` or even `Kubernetes` on more complex environments.

You better not take the second approach (`docker run`, `docker stop` & `docker start`) in those environments because at any moment in time you might lose that container and if you are solely dependent on that specific container or it's data, then you're gonna have a bad weekend.